# String index out of rage but cannot see why. Code does as I want it, but fails when submitted to the University checking system

Tags: java, oop, random, passwords

So I am currently taking an online course, and have progressed through fairly well until an exercise where I am supposed to create a password generator, with the password length given by the user.

The output of the code *seems* fine, it generates a password of the given length, but when submitted to the University online checking system; I receive a fail and this error:

**StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 26**

I'm new and really trying hard to crack this myself. But being new even the apparent solutions are difficult to understand.

I have placed the code here being unsure of how to minimise the code to show the problem.

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/320cab659ac9646e5162

I would appreciate any help. And most definitely will pay it forward should I have the opportunity. All the best, thanks.

Comment: no one is going to debug your code for you (especially when some index is out of rage!). try to see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringIndexOutOfBoundsException.html

Comment: @arghtype I'm very sorry. For a beginner it had me flustered. It won't happen again. Thanks for the link, it helped me understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is this line:

```
thisChar = passwordOptions.charAt(random.nextInt(passwordLength + 1));
```

passwordLength is a parameter that's passed in; when that's more than 25 there's a risk that you will choose a character that's not in the passwordOptions range. For smaller values of passwordLength are all the letters in your password at the beginning of the alphabet?

Comment: Your last question along with the other reply helped me solve the issue. I was accidentally saying take a passwordOptions character from a random index between 0 and passwordLength + 1. However the user could set the passwordLength so it wasn't choosing from the full range of characters available in password options.

I changed this parameter to (passwordOptions.length()); so that it could pick a character from the whole range of characters available, instead of just a range given by the user.

I'm sure you know I am just explaining for others and saying thanks.